# Can SLES get too old?

Tags: mixtures

I've been using SLES to break surface tension in some water solutions. However after a year or so it seems like the ability to break surface tension seems to wear off in the solutions. So my question is if this is supposed to happen? Does Sodium Lauryl Ether Sulphate lose its ability to break surface tension over time?

The SLES im using has also begun to smell bad from the tank, which made me curious about it wearing off or getting too old.